# Finding norm of integral operator on C[0,1]

Tags: integration, continuity, normed-spaces, operator-theory

I need help with the following:

> Find norm of inegral operator $K:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ which is defined as
> $$Kf(x) = \int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy, \forall f \in C[0,1], x \in [0,1],$$
> where $k \in C[0,1]^2$.

I have done this:
$$||Kf(x)|| = \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}|Kf(x)| = \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}|\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy| \leq \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)||f(y)|dy \leq ||f|| \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)|dy ,$$ so $$||K|| \leq \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)|dy .$$
I dont't know how to prove equality here, that is that $||K|| \geq \underset{x \in [0,1]}{max}\int_0^1 |k(x,y)|dy .$

Comment: Try to find an $f$ s.t. the bound is attained, i.e. s.t. $||Kf|| = \max_x \int_0^1|k(x,y)|dy$. That suffices to show $||K||_\infty = \max_x \int_0^1|k(x,y)|dy$

Comment: I get that, but the problem for me is to find $f$, such that $||f||=1$, and that $||Kf||$ attains the bound.